# How to filter confirm dialogs from different URLs in iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

My web page has more than one confirm dialog. They belong to different URLs

```
window.confirm("Hello") -> /hello
window.confirm("Exit") -> /confirm
```

I have my view controller:

```
class View2Controller: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
var webView: WKWebView!
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.myweb.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.load(myRequest)

... ...

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                ...
            }))
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
        completionHandler(true)
        }
```

Is it possible for me to use iOS alert ONLY for Exit confirmation in the /confirm URL and use web confirm dialog for Hello ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "web confirm" dialog when you're using `WKWebView`. All calls to `windowc.confirm`, `window.alert` and `window.prompt` get routed to your `WKUIDelegate` and it is up to your implementation of the various delegate methods what happens on those calls.

That said, you're not using the `completionHandler` correctly in your code - its argument should reflect the choice the user has made.